# PHP caching .NET basic authentication

Tags: php, .net, caching, curl, basic-authentication

I'm building a php app that uses an external .net restful API.
The API uses basic authentication and whenever I make a call I send user and password using CURL.

Everything works fine but for some reason the basic authentication takes some time (~150ms, i think the call reaches Active Directory) and i would like to just do it once.

What possibility do I have to cache this? When I connect to the API using the IE browser the first call takes more but the following ones are very fast. I want to do the same thing but I don't know through what mechanism.

Comment: Do you have access to change both sides? i.e can you adjust both the PHP and the .NET system?

Comment: Yes, the company developed both.